# Django - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'backend'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, active-model-serializers

I have problem with "ModuleNotFoundError" in my Django app.

This problem start when i write serializers.py and other files in my app.

All code you see it in my [Github](https://github.com/BMWdejf/Django_address_book)

This code is without syntax errors because I use PyCharm IDE.

When I start server I get this error:

[PyCharm IDE with terminal after run python server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5YO8.png)

I would appreciate any comments on where I made a mistake.

I expect my code to work correctly.

Comment: Well there is no backend module in your app ? But it's referenced in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

Comment: As @BDurand said and if I want to complete it, you have 2 apps that I checked:api and address_book. you don't have backend app that you wrote in installed list in settings.py. if you want to use your api urls.py, you should write "from api.views import ...", and also delete "backend" in INSTALLED_APPS list.